# ERROR Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, minimagick

I have an app that is using Imagemagick, but I had to rebuild my environment and now when I try and upload an avatar (which is why I am using Imagemagick), it keeps giving me the following error when I try to add an image.

```
Avatar Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed
```

I installed it in the folder that holds my app, but it seems as though the app is not recognizing the install. Is there a way to make the app recognize the minimagick or did I install it in the wrong place or am I completely off.

-UPDATE-

I uninstalled minimgick and reinstalled, but still get the same error, although it shows that it is installed. Here are my versions...

-imagemagick-6.9.1-6

-ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

-Rails 4.0.10

-running on a mac

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to install **libmagickwand-dev** in order to successfully complete the **rmagick** gem. Following command will do the job for you:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

On a Mac, you would run the following command:

```
brew install imagemagick # it requires you to install Homebrew first.
```

Comment: This is in the folder that contains my app right not the app itself?

Comment: You can run this command from any where in your terminal. Caution: It works on Ubuntu.

Comment: On Mac, you can do `brew install imagemagick`, but that itself requires you to install Homebrew first.

Comment: I am on a Mac and when I tried brew install imagemagick I got this... Warning: imagemagick-6.9.1-6 already installed

Comment: @SupremeA Then, you need to uninstall it, and re-install it.

Comment: So is this the same thing do I run brew install within my app folder or doesnt matter?

Comment: Nope, you can do it anywhere. Any thing that starts with `sudo` or `brew`, that isn't directory dependent.

Comment: I got it I had to install in on the virtual machine with Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: So I had the same issue, I ran above command and was able to add one image, the second time I am trying to add image, I get the same issue. 

any idea

Answer (score 53):

on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: For me, on Ubuntu 14.04, I needed this answer and @Arslan's answer.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04(I ran into this issue trying to deploy a rails web application that utilised imagemagick for image resizing)

Comment: I also needed both answers.

Comment: This comment was what i needed, also the accepted one above is part of the solution

Comment: You saved my evening, thank you!

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue and solved it with:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing`

Comment: i was able to convert images in console, but resque jobs would keep returning that error. after running the --fix-missing everything worked again

Answer (score 5):

`sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat`

Answer (score 2):

Just an update on my experience. I recently had the same issue with the latest version of ImageMagick 7.0.8-7. I fixed the problem by just downgrading to 6.9.... This solved the issue for some reason.

- I was on Windows btw. x64.

Comment: I've found the binaries here https://imagemagick.org/archive/binaries/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your system libraries. try this:-

`sudo apt-get -f install`

and then you would be able to upload it.

Answer (score 1):

For who's on **Cloud9** encountering the error:

> MiniMagick::Invalid (You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick
>   installed)

this solved for me:

```
sudo yum install ImageMagick
```